# How to use nested for loops in python?

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, nested-loops

I'm trying to create an array based on values from another data frame in Python. I want it to fill the array as such.

```
If x > or = 3 in the dataframe then it inputs a 0 in the array. 
If x < 3 in the dataframe then it inputs a 1 in the array.  
If x = 0 in the dataframe then it inputs a 0 in the array.
```

Below is the code I have so far but the result is coming out as just [0]

```
array = np.array([])

for x in df["disc"]:
    for y in array:    
        if x >= 3:
            y=0
        elif x < 3:
            y=1
        else:
            y=0
```

Any help would be much appreciated thank you.

Comment: You are not doing anything to `array`. Did you mean to add the `y` values to `array`? I don't think you need a nested loop here.

Answer (score 2):

When working with numpy arrays, it is more efficient if you can avoid using explicit loops in Python at all.  (The actual looping takes place inside compiled C code.)

```
disc = df["disc"]

# make an array containing 0 where disc >= 3, elsewhere 1
array = np.where(disc >= 3, 0, 1)

# now set it equal to 0 in any places where disc == 0
array[disc == 0] = 0
```

It could also be done in a single statement (other than the initial assignment of `disc`) using:

```
array = np.where((disc >= 3) | (disc == 0), 0, 1)
```

Here the `|` does an element-by-element "or" test on the boolean arrays.  (It has higher precedence than comparison operators, so the parentheses around the comparisons are needed.)

Comment: I believe it would be slightly more efficient to do this in a single statement rather than passing through the array again. That is, something like `array = np.where(disc >= 3 or disc == 0, 0, 1)`. This would avoid checking 0 equality for those values >= 3, thanks to the short circuiting of `or`, right?

Comment: @Zaxutic That's a possibility, thanks. You would have to use `|` instead of `or` though.

Comment: @Zaxutic I don't think the short-circuit evaluation is going to be available, because the operands of the `|` are still going to have to be boolean arrays that will need to be evaluated, but it might still be a bit quicker so I'll add it as an option.  (`or` would attempt to apply a truth value to the whole array.)

Comment: @Zaxutic note also that when using `|`, extra parentheses will be needed because, unlike `or`, the `|` has higher precedence than comparison operators

Comment: @Zaxutic Final comment - it might use more memory because both temporary boolean arrays will need to exist at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple problem. There are many ways to solve this, I think the easiest way is to use a list. You can use a [list](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-list/) and append the values according to the conditions.

```
array = []

for x in df["disc"]:
   if x >= 3:
       array.append(0)
   elif x < 3:
       array.append(1)
   else:
       array.append(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't seem to be doing anything to the array, as you are trying to modify the variable `y`, rather than the array itself. `y` doesn't reference the array, it just holds the values found. The second loop also doesn't do anything due to the array being empty - it's looping through 0 elements. What you need rather than another `for` loop is to simply append to the array.

With a list, you would use the `.append()` method to add an element, however as you appear to be using numpy, you'd want to use the `append(arr, values)` function it provides, like so:

```py
array = np.array([])

for x in df["disc"]:  
    if x >= 3:
        array = np.append(array, 0)
    elif x < 3:
        array = np.append(array, 1)
    else:
        array = np.append(array, 0)
```

I'll also note that these conditions can be simplified to combine the two branches which append a `0`. Namely, if x < 3 and x is not 0, then add a 1, otherwise add a 0. Thus, the code can be rewriten as follows.

```py
array = np.array([])

for x in df["disc"]:  
    if x < 3 and x != 0:
        array = np.append(array, 1)
    else:
        array = np.append(array, 0)
```