# Replace function python not working correctly

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I'm using a replace function to replace the value "C" or "c" with a 1 in a dataframe. Most of the values are correct but there are some values that pull through as just less than 1 or quite close to 0. This is the code I am using.

```
in ---> [-,C,-,-,-,C]

df["name"]= df["name"].replace("C" and "c", int(1))

out ---> [-,1,-,0.0054,-,0.9992]
```

The results in some cases change `c` to a `0.9992` or similar.

Any advice on this would be great. Thanks

Comment: Your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63300964/984421) suggests `df` is a pandas dataframe. If so, please make sure you add the appropriate tags to your question.

Answer (score 0):

`str.replace` can be used to replace only a single expression. To replace multiple expressions with the same value, you should use regex.
We will use here `re.sub` which is a substitution method that replaces every regex match with the given replacement string.

In this example, we want to replace either `c` or `C` with the char `1` and we want to do it on the string `Cabc`

```
import re

re.sub('[cC]', '1', 'Cabc')

# Output >>> 1ab1
```

Comment: @Yatin Added explanation

Answer (score 0):

`replace` works with one substring at a time.
So, in your case you can use `for` loop to call `replace` several times.

```
for str_to_replace in ("C", "c"):
    df["name"] = df["name"].replace(str_to_remove, '1')
```

But in case of handling upper/lower strings it is better to use regex.

Comment: The second argument of `replace` cannot be an `int`. But that assumes `df["name"]` holds a string, which I suspect is not the case.

Comment: I get the same results whether I use the for loop or not. It seems that the replace function works with the integer but it's just the issue with the results I am getting. I've included some more information in my question as it was a little unclear.